# Unable to get any responses from a php page using android studio

Tags: java, php, android, json, mysqli

If I run my code I get this JSONExeption error:

> "of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

I can see my php working in a browser but am unable to get anything from the app itself. I am trying to send a username and password and retrieve the username if the user exists. This is my php Code:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM user where 
email='$username' and password='$password'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];

if($data){
 echo json_encode($data);
}
else
{
  echo json_encode("false");
  //print "false";
}
mysqli_close($con)
```

This is the code in the app:

```
public String doWebService(String name, String pass)
{
Log.i(activityName, "Thread started; attempting to invoke web service");

String a   = name;
String b   = pass;
String sum = "Nothing";


HttpURLConnection con = null;
String responseStr = "";


try
{

    //****************************************************************//
    // Create a JSON object and use it to encode two integers with  //
    // the keys "paramA" and "paramB".                              //
    //****************************************************************//
    JSONObject toSendObject = new JSONObject();
    toSendObject.put("username", a);
    toSendObject.put("password", b);
    //String jsonStr = URLEncoder.encode(toSendObject.toString(), "UTF-8");
    String jsonStr = toSendObject.toString();




    Log.i(activityName, "JSON str" + jsonStr);
    //String urlStr = webServiceURL + "?" + jsonStr;
    String urlStr = webServiceURL + "?username=" + a +"&password=" + b;
    Log.i(activityName, "Sending this to web service: " + urlStr);
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);



    //********************************************************//
    // Create an HTTP connection, with various attributes.  //
    //********************************************************//
    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setReadTimeout(10000);
    con.setConnectTimeout(15000);       //Timeout in milliseconds.
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");        //Use HTTP GET
    con.setChunkedStreamingMode(0); //Default
    con.setDoInput(true);               //So that we can read response back
    con.connect();



    //********************************************************//
    // Now read the response.                                   //
    //********************************************************//
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));


    responseStr = in.readLine();

    in.close();
    con.disconnect();

    //******************************************************************//
    //Now parse the JSON result to get the sum.                       //
    //******************************************************************//

    Log.i(activityName, "Response str: " + responseStr);
    JSONObject  result = new JSONObject(responseStr);
    sum = result.toString();

    Log.i(activityName, "Response " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do your php code return in your browser?

Comment: As you can see in the code above I am trying to return the variable $data